# Personal document management

Tags: document-library, document-set, ecm

How can I manage user documents so only the user and the site owners can manage the documents?

Is there a way to automatically create a document set or document library for the user upon visiting the site for the first time?

I am trying to meet a project requirement to house enterprise annual training documents and certificates.

Comment: This sounds like a job for mysites & their shared documents. The first time requirement could be done with javascript checking for the existence of folders in the expected mysite location and if they aren't present, calling a workflow to create them. Would fall down if a user was to rename/move the doc library though.

Comment: I would like to keep the management of document library/document sets out of the user's hands and at the relevant site.  Is there no way to do this?

Comment: As above but instead of the mysite location, it could create a document library per user at the appropriate site. It could then assign permissions only to that user and the site owners. Bear in mind that you'd end up with a lot of doc libraries on the site... Unaware of any equiv OOTB function to meet your requirement.

Comment: Well thanks for the input.  I will continue prototyping until something stands out as a winner.